# Looking for a good replacement for Psyco (Python->C compiler)

Tags: python, c, django, compiler-construction, psyco

We really like [Psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) to speed things up, but it also has some drawbacks:

- it consumes too much memory
- it can also slow some code down
- compiling your code can take too much time
- it doesn't support 64-bit systems

What would be good alternatives (Django support required)?

Comment: Terminology nitpick: Psyco isn't a compiler from Python to C, it's a JIT compiler. Python to C compilers exist, but they are entirely different beasts. For starters, they don't support the full language and the compilation step can be quite a hassle compared to a regular interpreter integrating a JIT.

Comment: Ah.. First time we heard about it was here: http://highscalability.com/blog/2008/3/12/youtube-architecture.html where they are stating: "psyco, a dynamic python->C compiler".

Comment: so dont spread the mistake and point to the [right source](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/introduction.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using [PyPy](http://pypy.org/), which is an implementation of Python in Python. It is a replacement for the standard CPython implementation and boasts large speed increases.

From its website:

> **Speed:** thanks to its Just-in-Time compiler, Python programs often run
>   faster on PyPy.
>
> **Memory usage:** large, memory-hungry Python programs might end up taking less space than they do in CPython.
>
> **Compatibility:** PyPy is highly compatible with existing
>   python code. It supports ctypes and can run popular python libraries
>   like twisted and django.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that [PyPy runs django now](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/PyPy). PyPy is a pure-python jit for python code, and can provide dramatic speedups in some circumstances. Only a limited set of compiled modules are supported though.